# Android Aviary Library Error

Tags: android, aviary

I am working on an Image filter application, in this I have to apply some filters like pencil sketch, crop etc. for that I am using aviary library for android but when I call startActivityForResult() application get force close. Here are the logcats:

`11-23 13:31:03.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main`
`11-23 13:31:03.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4367): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jai.imagedemo/com.aviary.android.feather.FeatherActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout`

Any help in resolving this problem ?
Here is my code:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent( this, FeatherActivity.class );
        newIntent.setData(Uri.parse(imageFilePath));

        newIntent.putExtra( Constants.EXTRA_OUTPUT_FORMAT, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.name() );
        String mSessionId = StringUtils.getSha256( System.currentTimeMillis() + "pv1frfq8o76siqy" );

        newIntent.putExtra( Constants.EXTRA_OUTPUT_HIRES_SESSION_ID, mSessionId );
        newIntent.putExtra( Constants.EXTRA_IN_SAVE_ON_NO_CHANGES, true );

        startActivityForResult( newIntent, 2 );
```

And here is content of Manifest (for aviary library)

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.aviary.android.feather.FeatherActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:process=":standalone"
            android:screenOrientation="unspecified" />
       <provider
            android:name="com.aviary.android.feather.library.providers.FeatherContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.aviary.launcher.HiResProvider"
            android:exported="false" >
        </provider>
```

Comment: Did you get this solved? Just got the same error...

Comment: @sirvon I have download this sample https://github.com/sephiroth74/Aviary-Android-Sample-App and use sdk used in this sample and it worked

Comment: Ok thank you. Ill try...might need your assistance again.

Comment: have you created api_key of aviary. https://developers.aviary.com/docs/android/setup-guide#prerequisites may help

Comment: Just got the same error.. Anyone has solved it ?

Comment: github.com/sephiroth74/Aviary-Android-Sample-App
This library is absent now

Comment: @DeepakSharma get sample from this link https://developers.aviary.com/docs/android/setup-guide#prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution of your answer. Just add this line in your manifest :-

```
android:theme="@style/AviaryTheme"
```

Like that :-

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.aviary.android.feather.FeatherActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:process=":standalone"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" 
        android:theme="@style/AviaryTheme"/>
```

It will resolve Binary inflate problem. You must add aviary theme.